# LaTeX symbol under nabla

Tags: latex

In LaTeX, with \displaystyle , if I do something like:

```
\sum_{i=0}
```

then the i=0 appears under a giant Sigma. This is good.

Now, if I do (also in \displaystyle)

```
\nabla_{x}
```

the x does **not** appear under the nabla. It appears to the lower right. How can I make it appear under the nabla instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\mathop{\nabla}\limits_{x}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `\mathop`?

```
\mathop{\nabla}_{x}
```

Comment: ... and you would perhaps need an additional `\limits`.

Answer (score 1):

See the entry [Sub- and superscript positioning for operators ("limits")](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=limits) in the TeX FAQ.